# update GWT version for JDK9+

Tags: java, gwt, jetty

Currently we're using GWT 2.8.2. It's been so long since last update. The latest version is not working on JDKs higher than 1.8. It impedes progress of development. The only thing needed to do is just update embedded jetty version. I tried to update it myself but encountered tons of exceptions.

Comment: You should ask this question here: https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Comment: Then don't use the embedded Jetty ? I am using Java12 no problems with GWT...

Comment: Embedded jetty is much comfortable tool for debugging. You don't have to restart app server to see changes in browser. Just press ctrl+F9 (in intellij idea) and F5. I tried wildfly and glassfish. They both need re-compilation of whole project to have backend code updated. It takes about 8-10 minutes.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong...

Comment: what app server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The devil is in the detail.

Yes, using super dev move is extremely convenient BUT using that shortcut you cannot achieve dev-production parity exposing yourself to a myriad of possible issues that you won't be able to catch at dev time.

Using CodeServer with the "Dev Mode On" bookmarklet is as fast as SuperDev and not much less convenient (you need to click on a bookmark instead of F5).

With more information about your dev workflow we may be able to offer more specific help on how to better use CodeServer.

Comment: Thank you. I've already found out what was the problem. I successfully configured maven plugin for GWT and using SDM with payara. When I refresh page in browser GWT re-compiles changed code.

Comment: Can you share the solution? That code (or even just the pom.xml) may be very useful to someone down the line